# Performance of a big database, faster method: finding value with php or sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Lets say we have a very big (a lot of rows and cells) table in our database and we are looking for a very special value.

Which way will show us the result earlier?
a) put the table in a php array and get through this array
b) search for the value with sql commands

Comment: If the table is small enough, that you can put it into a PHP array, it is by definition not "very big" (by orders of magnitude).

Answer (score 7):

The database with an index on the column should be faster.

Even without an index, as you describe the problem, the database would be faster.  Just moving the data to the php array is an expensive operation.  Even if the database has to do a full table scan, it will only be moving back the row that you care about.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the columns you are searching on are properly indexed, using SQL directly should be substantially faster.  Otherwise, you have to select the entire table and loop through it  in PHP without the benefits of indexes.

If you cannot search on an index for whatever reason, I think that both methods would be very slow.  Essentially, there is no benefit to searching with PHP alone.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is big, fetching the data to fill the array will take time, and searching in an big array will be slow (unless you have a special indexing method for your array), whatever language you use , php, java, c# or other.

Put an index on the column you are searching for: row, cell or only value (if you search only for a value), it depends on your search.